# WPF Control's Nested property's data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to develop user control with some nested properties that allows to use databinding to set it. For example, I have something like this:

```
// Top level control
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public string TopLevelTestProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TopLevelTestPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TopLevelTestPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TopLevelTestPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TopLevelTestProperty", typeof(string), typeof   
           (MyControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

    // This property contains nested object
    public MyNestedType NestedObject
    {
        get { return (MyNestedType)GetValue(NestedObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NestedObjectProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NestedObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NestedObject", typeof(MyNestedType), typeof 
            (MyControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}

// Nested object's type
public class MyNestedType : DependencyObject
{
    public string NestedTestProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NestedTestPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NestedTestPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NestedTestPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NestedTestProperty", typeof(string), typeof
            (MyNestedType), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
}

// Sample data context
public class TestDataContext
{
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return "TEST VALUE!!!";
        }
    }
}
...
this.DataContext = new TestDataContext();
...
```

XAML:

```
      <local:mycontrol x:name="myControl" topleveltestproperty="{Binding Value}" >
         <local:mycontrol.nestedobject>
            <local:mynestedtype x:name="myNestedControl" nestedtestproperty="{Binding Value}" />
         </local:mycontrol.nestedobject>
      </local:mycontrol>
```

It works well for property TopLevelTestProperty, but it doesn't work for NestedTestProperty.
 It seems that nested bindings do not work. Can anybody help me please? Is there any way to make such binding?
 I think that it happens because of my nested object has no any reference to the top level object, so it cannot be resolved using MyControl's DataContext.

Comment: What do the binding errors say?

Comment: It said: "Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression: Path=Value; DataItem=null; target element is 'MyNestedType' target property is 'NestedTestProperty' (type 'String')"

Comment: You are lacking an [inheritance context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickkramer/archive/2006/08/18/705116.aspx)...

Comment: That seems so... I wonder if I can add it to my types...

Answer (score 0):

[H.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546730/h-b) right, nested control does not inherit DataContext from `mycontrol`.
Tyr out setting it explicitly:

```xml
<local:mycontrol x:name="myControl" 
                 topleveltestproperty="{Binding Value}" >          
   <local:mycontrol.nestedobject>             
           <local:mynestedtype x:name="myNestedControl" 
                               DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myControl,
                                                     Path=DataContext}"
                               nestedtestproperty="{Binding Value}" />          
  </local:mycontrol.nestedobject>       
</local:mycontrol>
```

Comment: So the only way to do that is to inherit mynestedtype from FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement(as there is no DataContext property in mynestedtype), isn't it ? But is there any way to do that for DependencyObject? FrameworkElement provides a lot of properties that I don't want to have.