# XAML WPF Control Templates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates

Is this

[WPF Control's Nested property's data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253908/wpf-controls-nested-propertys-data-binding?rq=1)

ever resolved in some way?

...

How can I:

1. declare a templated control that derives from Control
2. Have a middle - tier class that is a property
3. Set properties of the mid-level class from XAML

I have this code:

```
<cars:2016Model
    Engine.Power = "MOREMOREWARPSPEED"
>

public class 2016Model : Control
{
public 2016Model()
{
if (Date == 2016)
Engine = new 2016 Engine
}

public Engine { get; set; }

public class Engine 
{
    public virtual Double Power
    get
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class 2016Engine : Engine
 {
    public override Power
    {
        return 1000KWH;
    }
}

public class 2015Engine : Engine
{
    public override Power
    {
        return 350HP;
    }
}
```

I Want to swap out the mid-level class.

I want to swap out the templates and have different views of the same current incarnation of Model and Engine.

I want to template this, but I cannot see how to set properties of a swappable class from the Xaml.

Comment: I've tidied your question up a little, but I'm still not quite clear on the intent. Are you saying that you want to declare an instance of `2015Engine` or `2016Engine` in Xaml but don't know how to? What have you tried?

Comment: No I want to declare the instance in a specific Version of 2016Model.  In the constructor.  That's fine I can have different classes for each.  But I can't have different classes for each Sub-Model.  I need to set the Engine size from XAML.

Comment: What you've just said doesn't seem to make sense: you want to declare the instance of (I presume) `Engine` in the constructor, which you say is fine, but then you say you can't have different classes for the submodel (which you've just implied you can). Can you try to describe *precisely* what configuration of objects you want to be able to declare, and what you want your Xaml to contain? Right now I can't work that out.

Comment: @DanPuzey I need to set a property of a object that is a property from XAML.

Comment: You're still not explaining clearly. Let me try a different question: is your problem that your line `Engine.Power = "MOREMOREWARPSPEED"` is causing an error? If so: what's the error?  I ask this because in the code you've posted, `Power` is *read-only* - and is also declared with invalid syntax in your derived classes (so the code you've posted doesn't compile at all).

Comment: @DanPuzey Can you show how to set a property Engine.Size where Double Size is a read/write property of Engine and Engine TheEngine is a read/write property of Car2016; where Car2016 derives from Control and is visibily defined by a XAML ControlTemplate.  For Example "<templates:Car2016 TheEngine.Size = 100.0/>" for example.

Comment: @DanPuzey Why do I have to repeat the properties of the Engine object in the templated Control?  I can bind to a property of Engine in the Template or on the XAML instance <Car2016 x:name='foo'> <TextBlock Text={Binding Engine.Size ElementName='foo'}> but I can't *SET* the property from XAML.

Comment: @DanPuzey Would you see question edit? Can you answer the old question?

Comment: I am assuming u want to use a control for Engine, and tell it what type of Engine you want to show, and same control will display the required model.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Control will host different templates, showing different views of the same CarModel, but actually that is two different TrimModels because the template is totally different.  But underneath, the Engine is the same year.  But even so, The Engine can be swapped out and the user doesn't need to know the details of that because each Control derivation is a concrete classes that shows up in INtellisense when user types <CarTemplates; and Engine specialization Engine2015 or Engine 2016 is made concrete in the constructor of the Control.  But stil I want user to set Engine.Size.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you want to do, but I have a suspicion.

First, your code doesn't compile for a variety of reasons -- among other things, you can't start an identifier with a digit. But that's a quibble -- assume these model objects:

```
public class Car2016Model : Control
{
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }
}

public class Engine
{
    public virtual double Power => 0;
}

public class Engine2016 : Engine
{
    public override double Power => 1000;
}

public class Engine2015 : Engine
 {
    public override double Power => 350;
}
```

You can then declare cars in XAML with different engines as follows:

```
<cars:Car2016Model>
    <cars:Car2016Model.Engine>
        <cars:Engine2015 />
    </cars:Car2016Model.Engine>
</cars:Car2016Model>
<cars:Car2016Model>
    <cars:Car2016Model.Engine>
        <cars:Engine2016 />
    </cars:Car2016Model.Engine>
</cars:Car2016Model>
```

Of course, if you also want to display something useful, you need to provide a control template for the `Cars2016Model` control:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="cars:Car2016Model" x:Key="Template">
            <Grid Background="Cyan">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Engine.Power, Mode=OneTime}" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Reference the template from the control:

```
<cars:Car2016Model Template="{StaticResource Template}">
    <cars:Car2016Model.Engine>
        <cars:Engine2015 />
    </cars:Car2016Model.Engine>
</cars:Car2016Model>
```

I *hope* this is what you were asking.

Comment: This is one pattern I am looking at, but am not satisfied with.  I want to use several different templates for the same *BASE* class deriving from Control, so for example <ControlTemplate TargetType="cars:Car">.   So in this vein, I want to be able to declare multiple classes deriving from this base and in the constructor I will specialize the engine type.  But I want the template to be reusable between all of these.

Comment: I don't want the end-user of the control to have to specify, in XAML, the Engine Specialization.  I want each of these to be a concrete class that shows up in XAMl-Intellisense when I enter the "<car:" namespace.  So I need the Engine as a generic object in the Templated Control, and to instantiate in the constructor for each concrete specialization.  But I then want to allow the user to Drill Down into the Engine and specify, at the proper time, the Engine size.

Comment: Would you see question edit? Can you answer the old question?

Comment: I had a go at the old question, but I was unable to make the binding work, unfortunately. From the [linked blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickkramer/archive/2006/08/18/705116.aspx), it looks like this can't be done for classes lacking an inheritance context.

Comment: So in that example if I simply say "nestedtestproperty = 'foo'" will that work? Is that because of the inheritance context?!

Comment: I'm not on my dev box, so can't check, but I'd think so, yes.

Comment: Ok,that does seem to work, if you instantiate the NestedObject in the XAML.  But I really don't want that.  I want a concrete class that shares the same template across multiple versions, and each version instantiates a specialization of a base class Engine in it's constructor.  In that case there is no "syntax" for <MyControl  NestedObject.NestedTestProperty="test123"> It says Nested Types are not supported.  Is there another pattern you can think of to further refine these classes I have to concrete implementations so the user only.

Comment: Has to punch in, <Templates:  and will see all the concrete implementations, select one, but then be able to further refine by specifying an Engine.Size?