# Expose inner controls in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

In wpf a ListBox has a ScrollViewer property and the intellisense shows it with a 'brackets' icon:
[image]

It allows you to navigate its inner properties:
[image]

In my custom control I want to expose an inner ListBox so I created a dependency property of type ListBox. 
The result is a 'ListBox' property that shows up in the intellisense with a 'wrench' icon and non-navigable inner properties.

How can i mimic what the ListBox control does with the ScrollViewer?

Comment: A duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253908/wpf-controls-nested-propertys-data-binding

Comment: I had a look at how ListBox was coded on referencesource.microsoft.com before posting this question. I did not see any inner type. I don't think this question is a duplicate of the one you link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollViewer is a ContentControl which has these three Attached Properties

- CanContentScroll
- HorizontalScrollBarVisibility
- VerticalScrollBarVisibility

So here ListBox sets these attached properties on itself that ScrollViewer exposes and only attached properties can be set like this.

Your case is different, you want to directly set/bind properties of child control on parent control which is not a best approach to follow. Rather you can expose properties you want you child to be bound to as dependency properties on custom control and bind child internally to those. In this way when you change those properties on custom control, child will also be updated.

Comment: can you please provide an example for the first case you describe? i would like to try it out but i'm a little mazed

Comment: how do the listbox set those attached properties on itself?